# MS Access 2007 query pulls same records multiple times

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a problem, my query in MS Access 2007 pulls same records multiple times.

There are two tables : sales, products

- Product Table

  ID | Name | Price | Code

  01 | PEN  | 0.10$ | 01

  02 | ITEM | 0.20$ | 2567
- Sales table:

  ID | Code | Amount

  1  | 01   | 4

  2  | 2567 | 2
- And there's query

  SELECT Product.Name, Product.Price, Sales.Amount

  FROM Product, Sales

  WHERE Product.Code IN (SELECT Sales.Code FROM Sales);
- Thats the result

Name    Price   Amount

PEN     $0.10   4

PEN     $0.10   4

ITEM    $0.20   2

ITEM    $0.20   2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to

```
SELECT Product.Name, Product.Price, Product.Amount
FROM Product, Sales
WHERE Product.Code = Sales.Code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is currently joining every record in Product to every record in Sales, resulting in multiples.  You need to do a join between them, either in the WHERE clause like Yousaf suggested, or like this, which is more the standard way to do it:

```
SELECT Product.Name, Product.Price, Sales.Amount
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Sales ON Product.Code = Sales.Code
```